# Regex to replace parentheses with square bracket

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I need to convert some variables that use parentheses instead of bracket in a Javascript file. For example, MyVariable(i) should be MyVariable[i].

I use the ***Find and Replace*** tool of Visual Studio with this Regex :

```
MyVariable\({(.+)}\)
```

and replace with:

```
MyVariable\[\1\]
```

This work fine for case like :

```
asdas.MyVariable(i+1)
asdas.MyVariable(i)
asdas.MyVariable(i).asd
MyVariable(i+1)
```

But doesn't work for case like

```
if (parseInt(OtherObject.MyVariable(i+1).Dest.XYZ)==SINK_STATE_TYPE || OtherObject.MyVariable(i).X == "ok")
```

The last one will do take the first parentheses and the last one of the line and act weird. What do I need to change in the Regex to be able to make it works with line that has multiple parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern is greedy. The `(.+)` part matches everything, including a closing parenthesis `)` character until it reaches the last `)` character. To make it non-greedy you can use `#` instead of `+`, which means "match one or more occurrences of the preceding expression, and match as few characters as possible." In .NET this is usually handled by placing a `?` after it, such as `.+?` but the Visual Studio regex flavor is different and uses the `#` metacharacter instead.

The updated pattern becomes:

```
MyVariable\({(.#)}\)
```

You can also use `[^)]+`, which matches any character that is not a `)` character. When it encounters a `)` it will stop matching. This alternate pattern is:

```
MyVariable\({([^)]+)}\)
```

If you're familiar with the .NET regex flavor you might be interested in checking out the [Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), which has extended Find/Replace to allow the .NET regex flavor to be used.